# Twilio Autopilot Allow Barge In

Tags: twilio

I would like to allow callers to barge in during a Say Action in Twilio Autopilot. is that possible? At the start of the call, I read off a list of possible things to say to the bot - but the list is growing and would like for users to be able to interrupt the reading and go to the appropriate action without having to wait for it to end.

Comment: In my testing barge works when making a voice call into Autopilot via a Twilio number.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

The docs are not yet updated, but *barge* is supported. By default, customers could cut-off a `Say` or a `Collect` using speech. If you would like to disable `barge`, you could set it to `false` in the `listen` or `collect` property below `speech`.

That JSON might look something like:

```
{
    "actions": [
        {
            "say": "Hi, how can I help you today?"
        },
        {
            "listen": {
                "barge": true
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Or in a more complex `say`:

```
{
  "actions": [
    {
      "say": {
        "speech": "Hello! how can I help you. Say or press 1 for sales, 2 for support."
      }
    },
    {
      "listen": {
        "voice_digits": {
          "redirects": {
            "1": "task://sales",
            "2": "task://support"
          }
        },
        "barge": false
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Or in a `Collect` that might look like:

```
{
   "actions":[
      {
         "collect":{
            "name":"collect_custom",
            "questions":[
               {
                  "question":"What office are you based out of? Press 1 for San Francisco. 2 for Mountain View. 3 for Remote",
                  "name":"twilio_office",
                  "type":"twilio_office",
                  "voice_digits":{
                     "mapping":{
                        "1":"San Francisco",
                        "2":"Mountain View",
                        "3":"Remote"
                     }
                  },
                  "barge":false
               }
            ],
            "on_complete":{
               "redirect":{
                  "uri":"https://example.com/collect",
                  "method":"POST"
               }
            }
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

Let me know if this helps at all!

Comment: This is excellent, and helped me a lot. Thank you! I tried to upvote, but my reputation is too low to count